# Read Values from XML , and make Text Boxes and fill the values in those text boxes dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, visual-studio-2008, functional-programming

I have an Xml file

Now i want to read all the sub tags which are ( RECORDNUMBER ,RECORDCATEGORY,ACTIONFLAG ...... respectively) in C# Visual studio 2008

and Automatically make Text Boxes and fill these records in those text boxes when this file is uploaded on another form ..

for eg , this file has 7 sub tags , so it should make 7 text boxes dynamically and fill the tag value in  those text boxes

Can any one help PLZZZ IN C# Visual studio 2008

Comment: try using Linq To Xml http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Please put an example of the XML

Comment: <CARD Ignore="false" Optional="true">  
  <RECORDNUMBER  lengthType="fixed" length="6"  datatype="Number"  format="^\d{6}$" />
  <RECORDCATEGORY  lengthType="fixed" length="2"  datatype="varchar" value="DA" format="^.+$" />
  <ACTIONFLAG   lengthType="fixed" length="2"  datatype="Number" format="^00$" />
  <CARD_INTERFACING_NO lengthType="Max"   length="20" datatype="varchar" format="^.*$" />
  <CARDNAME   lengthType="Max"   length="30" datatype="varchar" format="^.+$" />
  <HOMEADDRESS1   lengthType="Max"   length="30" datatype="varchar" format="^.*$" />
  <HOMEADDRESS2   lengthType="Max"

Comment: Can any one plz help ...